# How to disable results opening in new tab for Yahoo search

Tags: safari, search, yahoo

I switched to from Google to Yahoo as my default search engine for Safari.

The search itself works fine, but then when I click an item on the search results page, it will open it in a new tab by default, rather than in the same tab that the results were in. I really prefer the latter behavior, because otherwise my browser window quickly fills up with search results tabs that I have no use for. I also don't see myself getting used to manually closing every single search result tab I open during the day.

Hence, I was wondering if anyone else has experienced this and if there's perhaps a way to disable this "feature".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This not an Apple issue becuase it's a Yahoo preference setting

What you need to do is set your [search preferences](http://us.yhs4.search.yahoo.com/preferences/preferences) so that search results open in the current tab.

Once you set this, it will be active across all browsers in all platforms.

[image]